# Why changes is one array data changing the value of another array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Why the arr[1] value is changing when changing the value of arr1[1]? and similarly why it is changing when `((int[])o)[1] = 1000`;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        arr[1] = 10;
        Object o = arr;
        int[] arr1 = (int[])o;
        arr1[1] = 100;
        Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);
        ((int[])o)[1] = 1000;
        Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);
    }
}
```

Why the answer is 100 and 1000?

This code is question-5 from https://www.techbeamers.com/csharp-coding-interview-questions-developers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the arr[1] value is changing when changing the value of arr1[1]?

This is your first question, but keep it now after answering the second.

> and similarly why it is changing when `((int[])o)[1] = 1000;`

This is your second question.
Answer is by seeing what is the initial value of `o` variable.

```cs
Object o = arr;
```

The previous line sets `o` to `arr`, but it's not copying the elements from `arr` to `o`. They're reference types, so, now both `o` and `arr` refers to the **same** memory block. Therefore, any changes made to `arr` will affect `o` and vice-versa. Because they're sharing the same memory.

Now, let's get back to your first question:

It's really the same answer as the second one.

```cs
int[] arr1 = (int[])o;
```

The previous line sets `arr1` to `o`, but again, they just holds the same memory address.

To summarize:

- You created `arr`
- You created `o` and made its reference the same as `arr`, so they both share the same memory.
- You created `arr1` and made its reference the same as `o` which also same as `arr`. so, `arr` and `arr1` and `o`, all have the same reference.

Any change to any of them will affect the others.

Comment: "Why ? Because you changed it!" ... That doesn't help to explain to OP why changing the value in the second array also causes the value to change in first array. I assume you noticed these are two different arrays?

Comment: @ADyson, I didn't notice that one of them is `arr` and the other is `arr1`, thought there is only `arr` and `o`. but the same concept explained in the second part of the current answer still holds for the first part. But I'm going to edit my answer anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me understand the code

Answer (score 0):

arr, arr1 and o point to the same base memory address of the same array.

In C# an array is used by reference.

Reference is a hidden managed pointer to forget to manage it.

Comment: To make it more clear (I hope). You created a new array, and made the variable `arr` reference it. Then you set the second element in that array to 10 through the arrow variable. Then you set the variable `o` to reference the same array (that `o` is of type `object` doesn't really matter; variables of type object can refer to anything). Then you set variable `arr1` to refer to the same array. At this point, `arr`, `o` and `arr1` all refer to the same thing, that array you created; though access to the array through `o` requires casting it back to an array reference.

Comment: That's it. Casting is needed to match the type of the thing referenced, the array.